# DatePicker doesn't work in a React custom Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-hooks

The [React DatePicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) I'm currrently using has a onChange property that let's you track the selected dates

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  startDate={startDate}
  endDate={endDate}
  onChange={e => setValue(e)}
/>
```

When I use the useState() hook in a straightforward manner, it works perfectly fine:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState()
```

However, I need to use it in a custom Hook to put together various variables.  The `onChange()` property fails to work in that setting. No errors, just simply no interaction.

For example, I define the custom Hook as following and call from the `onChange()` property as before, nothing happens:

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()
  return [value, () => setValue()]
}
const [value, setValue] = useCustomHook()
```

Comment: `setValue(e)` is calling a function with 1 argument, `setValue()` with no arguments => the 2 different function calls will do 2 different things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That may be happening because the setter is not receiving any arguments and hence, not updating the value of the state.

Try returning your hook this way:

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()
  return [value, (val) => setValue(val)]
}
```

Or simply passing `setValue` directly:

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()
  return [value, setValue]
}
```